# Application is starting even after closing

Tags: android

This is my first activity and when I press the back button in the phone , the app closes, but the second activty is popping up even after it closes! may be because the thread is still running? but i tried destroying it but of no avail! any suggestions

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle myclass) {
    super.onCreate(myclass);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    timer = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            finally {
                Intent openStarting = new Intent("nik.tri.MENU");
                startActivity(openStarting);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    timer.destroy(); // tried timer.stop() as well 
    finish();
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `Thread` is involved in that process:

when you press the back button, you do not destroy nor stop your app, you just make it invisible. `onPause()` is called at that time, but `finish()` just terminates your `Activity`'s workflow: the `Activity` it is still in memory and **WILL** be destroyed at some point, later. So the `Thread` keeps running.  And calling `Thread.stop()` is not efficient [as explained in the doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28%29):

> This method is deprecated. because stopping a thread in this manner is unsafe and can leave your application and the VM in an unpredictable state.

So the `Thread` is still runnning, and this is why the app restarts after 3 seconds. Or I should say, start a new `Activity`.

I don't see why you are using this `Thread` that starts a new `Activity` after 3 second, but taking this for granted, you should:

- Use a `boolean` in your `Thread` to determine whether you can start or not:

  ```
  timer = new Thread() {
      public void run() {
          try {
              sleep(3000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } 
          finally {
              if (!paused) {
                  Intent openStarting = new Intent("nik.tri.MENU");
                  startActivity(openStarting);
              }
          }
      }
  };
  ```
- And handle that flag in `onPause()` / `onResume()`:

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
      paused = true;
      super.onPause();

      finish(); // well, I don't get that either, but I take it for granted as well.
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      paused = false;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

try to kill the application in OnDestroy method.

```
int pid=android.os.Process.myPid();
 android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

try this, may it helps you